# validation in the collection class not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following Model:

```
public partial class EmployeeInfo
{
    public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
   [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } =null!;
    public virtual ICollection<EmergencyInfo> EmergencyInfos { get; } = new List<EmergencyInfo>();
}
```

I have another Model class for EmergencyInfo

```
public partial class EmergencyInfo
{
    public int EmergencyInfoId { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
 public virtual EmployeeInfo? EmployeeInfo { get; set; } 
}
```

Although the Firstname is required in EmergencyInfo Model. When I click the submit button, it does not show that Firstname is required . It does show that LastName is required because that field exists in the EmployeeInfo model. below is my razor page:

```
@model AckPackage.Models.EmployeeInfo
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

 <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control input-lg" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

        <div class="col">
                                <label asp-for="@Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[i].FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input name="EmergencyInfos[@i].FirstName" value="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[0].FirstName)? "": @Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[0].FirstName)" class="form-control" />
                     

   <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[0].FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
```

Lastname not filled always displays LastName is required, but Firstname from emergencyInfo always goes to HTTPPost without showing validation error message.

If I remove tolist() as suggested in the comment below then I get this compilation error:

[image]

Comment: It looks like that you are only accessing the first item in the list of EmergencyInfos in your Razor page, but you should be checking for validation on all items in the list.

Comment: yes, I am. I didnt want to post the entire Razor page. I just wanted to show the issue that i am having

Comment: Remove ToList, I've never seen anything like this, Just fix your model and use Model.EmergencyInfos[i].FirstName

Comment: I removed toList() and pasted the error in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure `asp-for` tag helper for `input` like below:

```
<div class="col">
    <label asp-for="@Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[0].FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="EmergencyInfos.ToList()[@i].FirstName" name="EmergencyInfos[@i].FirstName"value="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[0].FirstName)? "": @Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[0].FirstName)" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[0].FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```